# why is free() adding weired character on a string pointer in c?

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

I'm new to C language, less than two months old, but i have been experiencing a problem with malloc, realloc and free. I was writting a code to print numbers on stdout, and my method was, converting it to a string first and then printing it. Here is my code;(count is for keeping record of char printed.)

```
int print_num(int num, int count)
{
    int i = 0, len;
    char last, *ptr2, *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (num == 0)
        return (print_char('0', count));
    if (num < 0)
        count = print_char('-', count);
    num = abs(num);
    while (num != 0)
    {
        last = (num % 10) + '0';
        if (i == 0)
            *(ptr) = last;
        else
        {
            ptr2 = (char *)realloc(ptr, i + 1);
            *(ptr2 + i) = last;
            ptr = ptr2;
        }
        num /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    len = strlen(ptr);
    for (i = len; i > 0; i--)
        count = print_char(ptr[i - 1], count);
    free(ptr);
    return (count);
}
```

The problem is that, the code works fine without `free(ptr)`or `free(ptr2)`. When i call the function more than once in another function, i get weired char at the end of the string pointer ptr.
Example when printing two numbers in a row

```
print_num(39, 0)
print_num(39, 0)
```

i get

```
Length:[39, U�39]
```

when i delete `free(ptr)`, the code works fine, but their will be a memory leak.
How can i make this work?

```
int print_char(char c, int count)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return (count + 1);
}
```

Comment: How are you getting `"Length:"` in your output if it's not in the code you're showing? Post a [mre].

Comment: It's from another variadic function that calls this function to print it's vaues; ```_printf("Length: [%d, %d]\n", var1, var2);``` where var1 and var2 are both 39. I've added a condition in it ```if (current_char == '%' && next_char == 'd') print_num(va_arg(lst, int));```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `strlen` on an array of bytes that isn't a string.

A string in C is a null terminated sequence of characters.  You build up an array of characters in the memory pointed to by `ptr`, but don't add a terminating null byte.  This by itself isn't a problem, but then you call `strlen` on it which expects a null terminated string.  This results in the function reading past the end of allocated memory, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You already have the length of the array stored in `i`, so there's no need to call `strlen`.  Just use that.

```
len = i;
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I'll correct it and i'll give a feedback if all goes well

Comment: it worked when with your suggestion. the problem i think, it was iterating through the pointer more times than it should. Thanks ....